# Localhost vs 127.0.0.1 using tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I'm using tomcat7 in Ubuntu 14.04.
My problem is simple: when i run `http://localhost:8080` it works. But when i run `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` it doesn't work. I got `Etat HTTP 404 - /`.

What is the problem ? and how can i resolve it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you did a typo  there **127.0.0.7** should be **127.0.0.1**. If still doesnt work try to update /etc/hosts file and add localhost to 127.0.0.1 mapping.

**EDIT**
Seems like you did type in question and edited. Also take a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/218666/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-only-listen-to-127-0-0-1)

Comment: if you run cat /etc/hosts command you should see something like localhost 127.0.0.1,  which means each time i open this ip forward to this host. https://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2006/12/05/user-feedback-etchosts-explained-ubuntu-510-6061-610/